# Selected cell is deselected when switch to other page

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I make a custom calendar using `UICollectionView`. From the calendar when I selected some dates and move forward to next month, then back again to the previous month, the selected item is deselected. Maybe it happens for reusable cell. How can I solve this problem. 
For better understand what I want:

1. From `September` I select 4,5 then move to `August/July/November` (In this month maybe select some other dates or not)
2. Then return to `September`. In `September` I want to showed 4,5 as selected

I tried this using `didSelectItemAt` indexPath, but when return back to the `September` the selected item is deselected

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarDateRangePickerCell {
            if cell.isSelected == true {
                cell.backgroundColor = .blue
                cell.label.textColor = .white
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
            selectedDate = cell.date!
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an array of selected Cells. If you are using a model to set data to cell, you can create an array of selected models. or you can create an array of selected rows.

Let's say you are using a model.

```
var selectedDates: [DateModel] = []
```

Then

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarDateRangePickerCell {

        selectedDate = cell.date!
        if !selectedDates.contains(dataSourceModel[indexPath.row]) {
          selectedDates.append(dataSourceModel[indexPath.row])
        }
    }

}
```

then in your cellForItem

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  if selectedDates.contains(dataSourceModel[indexPath.row]) {
     cell.isSelected = true
  }
}
```

Also make sure you remove you model when unSelected

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedDates.contains(dataSourceModel[indexPath.row]) {
          selectedDates.remove(dataSourceModel[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
```

*may contain some syntax error, but you can follow this path to get where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cells in `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are reused when you scroll, that is why you should store which days selected in another place. Then, in `cellForItem` you should set `isSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `false` in `viewDidLoad()`?

> A Boolean value indicating if the controller clears the selection when the collection view appears.
>
> The default value of this property is true. When true, the collection view controller clears the collection view’s current selection when it receives a viewWillAppear(_:) message. Setting this property to false preserves the selection.

Source: [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller/1623977-clearsselectiononviewwillappear)